# Use youtube-video as background on a not 100% width wrapper

Tags: html, css, youtube

I want to use a youtube-video as the background of a container-block. This container-block isn't 100vw so I guess I need a bit of a different approach then the classic one. Therefore I tried that one here: https://codepen.io/daiaiai/pen/ygeyLG with that "code":

```
$color_1:rgb(25,29,184);
$color_7:rgb(241,90,111);

* {
  vertical-align:top;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:auto;
  border:0;
}

.sw_header{
    height:92vh;
    width:100vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sw_header-links{
    width:40%;
    height:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background: $color_1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.sw_header-links-videowrapper{
    //position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    //width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.sw_header-links-videowrapper iframe{
    //position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 320%;
  width:180%;
  //height: 200%;
}

.sw_header-rechts{
    display: inline-block;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    background:$color_7;
    padding:50px;
}
```

and the html-code therefore with that code:

```
<header class="sw_header">
<div class="sw_header-links">
<div class="sw_header-links-videowrapper">
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/W0LHTWG-UmQ?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=W0LHTWG-UmQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
<div class="sw_header-rechts">
<h4>The other content <br/> The other contentblock</h4></div>
</header>
```

But I do now get the problem of not being able to fit the video 100% to the container, like a background-size:cover; would do. Which values would I need for the video to be 
- 100% height of the container
- proportionally correct scaling of the width
- alignment left top without any black backgrounds
- so that as a result of most device dimensions the videos width will be cropped.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Can you create and share a JSFiddle of this? I will definitely help you then.

Comment: sure: https://jsfiddle.net/daiaiai/j1x5mxp9/

Comment: There is not video shown in this fiddle. Which element do you want to fit?

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your CSS :

```
iframe{
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```